# BCM43142 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, wubi, dell

I tried many solutions given for other BCM43 drivers and nothing helped me!! I saw one guy posted that WiFi wont work for Wubi Ubuntu of BCM43142.

I do not have ethernet connection too in my home!! I use my own mobile hotspot for this! So WiFi is must for me... Buh unfortunately nothing worked for me!!

Anyone using WiFi in BCM43142 hardware?

My ubuntu is Wubi. If anyone got solution please help me.

Comment: Did you try USB tethering?

Comment: can you access the Internet any other way on your ubuntu install ? ie, a friends phone, home wifi, as Helio said USB tether ?

Comment: @helio: But i need wifi of its own for my laptop!!!

Comment: @mark: no...no other way for the connection!! I have to check in my friend's home and try!! If i got ethernet connect what are the working steps ?

Comment: OK, first tell me 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu ?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15R 5537 with 64bit Windows 7 and Wubi Ubuntu 14.04 with 64bit

Comment: The only step that you may do when connected to ethernet is `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter` and then reboot. If doesn't work, then ask here again

Comment: Ok...i will try and let you know :) thanks for the quick reponse :)

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: @MohammedShamshid: Did it work?

Comment: Yes...installing of dkms and the bcmwl solved my issue xD

Answer (score 1):

The package *bcmwl-kernel-source* is correct for your device. If you still have the install DVD or USB, then you can find it and its prerequisite there. Navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop. Now navigate to pool > main > d > dkms and drag and drop dkms to your desktop. Now install both with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.